# Realizar operação OR entre duas models no Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize-js

Na minha tabela Proposta possuo duas foreign keys que referenciam a mesma tabela(Produtor), preciso fazer um where para verificar se existe um produtor com um documento igual ao pesquisado em uma dessas foreign keys

Exemplo:

```
     Proposta ->  id| nome_proposta | valor | produtor1 | produtor2 |
                   0| proposta vida | 12.00 |    0      |      1    |

     Produtor1 -> id| nome |documento
                   0| João | 12543    

     Produtor2 -> id| nome |documento
                   1| Lucas| 85476
```

Segue a parte do Sequelize:

```
where: {
                [Op.or]: {
                    {
                        model: Produtor,
                        as: "produtor1",
                        where: {
                            documento : documento_produtor,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        model: Produtor,
                        as: "produtor2",
                        where: {
                            documento : documento_produtor,
                        },
                    },
                }
            }
```

Existe alguma forma de realizar esse Select que me retornaria os dois produtores daquela proposta mas que só um possuísse o documento igual? Por que nos meus teste só consigo pesquisar um de cada vez.

Obs: Não tenho como saber se o produtor que eu quero ta na primeira ou na segunda foreign key

Comment: Não entendi direito. Você quer que o `Op.or` funcione como "ou exclusivo" (xor)?

Comment: @RafaelTavares Seria exclusivo de qualquer jeito, pois documento é um valor único. A questão é que esse OR não funciona. E não sei como fazer esse OR com include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema da sua query é que você não colocou o `Op.or` como sendo um array. Faça a alteração e veja se funciona.

Se não funcionar, eu encontrei um [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38825244/8839059) de query que você especifica diretamente dentro do `where` a coluna de uma tabela associada:

```js
{
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            { '$produtor1.documento$': documento_produtor },
            { '$produtor2.documento$': documento_produtor }
        ]
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: Produtor,
            as: "produtor1"
        },
        {
            model: Produtor,
            as: "produtor2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado Rafael. A solução foi colocar esse $ antes e depois do campo.